# Inline editing of a field using react, redux and redux-form. Should I do it this way?

Tags: redux, redux-form

Rather than opening a form for an entire editable object, I would like to create inline editing of individual fields from the object.

I'm using reactjs, redux and redux-form for my other forms so I thought the best place to start would be trying to use redux-form for the inline editing as well. This would save me from having two different ways to do validation, state management, etc.

But this would mean I would have a form for every editable object plus a form for every field on those objects. It could be hundreds of forms. Aside from the maintainability issues that would come with this approach, I'm wondering what the performance implications would be.  How would redux-form behave in that case? Does it mean there would be hundreds of reducers listening to every action in the redux store or are these reducers only listening while the page containing the form is displayed?

Comment: Could you please clarify on what do you mean 'inline editing' ?

Comment: I'm sure you know that redux-form supports dot notation in field names and also you can create form sections as repeatable form components

Comment: By inline editing, I mean being able to click on a displayed value and have it change into an input field with that value pre-populated. The input component would have its own submit and cancel buttons.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a sort of working exmaple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

update

I think it should be quite possible to create a redux-form for inline fields on edit and remove when editing stops.

Here is a working example (open dev tools to see the actions running)
https://codesandbox.io/s/13nywm3k2j

It obviously needs some data persisting mechanism after form is sumbitted

---

The form data not necessarily should be 'flat', it can be nested with help of dot notation, like

```
<Form>
  <Field name='title' />
  <Field name='object.title' />
  <Field name='object.mass' />
  <Field name='object.weight' />
</Form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. That will be helpful if I decide to go down the redux-form route. But my main question is about the performance implications. I'm not familiar with the lifecycle of react components and redux-form reducers etc. Would this approach result in hundreds of actions being fired?

Comment: Hi! There is only one redux-form reducer, the one you connect to redux with combineReducers. In this particular example the actual redux-form object is being created when the editing start and disappears after that. All the other time it's just a plain text field (of which you can have many on the page). So I can't see and perfomance reductions. Of course when you type inside the field, redux-form always reduces current state to a new state on every tap, but that's how it works

Comment: Thanks very much, very helpful.